# java .au file analyze header byte by byte

Tags: java, file, audio, byte, inputstream

I am trying to write a program that accepts a .au audio file and displays the header size, data size, encoding, sample rate, and number of channels. (Plus anything else that might be in a .au file.) I think I've gotten it to mostly work, but it's not returning the right sample rate. The code I wrote below outputs the following:

```
Header Size: 24
Data Size: 105
Encoding: 3
Sample Rate: -197
# of Channels: 2
```

The sample rate is actually 48000,  not -197. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. (And I'm also a bit confused on what data size represents.) If known, I would also like to know the byte by byte layout of a .au audio file. I think I have it right but I would like to be sure.

Here's a link to the .au audio format file description: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_file_format, http://docs.python.org/2/library/sunau.html.

I can't use a java library for this project. I need to analyze the file byte by byte. The code is written below and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
try {
    File originalFile = new File("inputSample.au");
    File newFile = new File("outputSample.au");
    FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(originalFile);
    FileOutputStream outputFile = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    byte[] newBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    int a = 0;
    while ((length = inputFile.read(buffer)) > 0) { //input file gets read into buffer (1024 bytes per loop)
        if (a == 0)
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++)
                newBuffer[i] = buffer[i];
        a++;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    outputFile.close();
    int headerSize = newBuffer[4] + newBuffer[5] + newBuffer[6] + newBuffer[7];
    int dataSize = newBuffer[8] + newBuffer[9] + newBuffer[10] + newBuffer[11];
    int encoding = newBuffer[12] + newBuffer[13] + newBuffer[14] + newBuffer[15];
    int sampleRate = newBuffer[16] + newBuffer[17] + newBuffer[18] + newBuffer[19];
    int channels = newBuffer[20] + newBuffer[21] + newBuffer[22] + newBuffer[23];
    System.out.println("Header Size: " + headerSize);
    System.out.println("Data Size: " + dataSize);
    System.out.println("Encoding: " + encoding);
    System.out.println("Sample Rate: " + sampleRate);
    System.out.println("# of Channels: " + channels);
}
catch (Exception exception) {System.out.println("Exception: " + exception.toString());}
```

Comment: A link to the file format description would be useful here

Comment: This is homework. So just a few hints: The way you're calculating the e.g. 'headerSize' is wrong (use the file formats magic number to check) - you cannot simply use addition; 'outputFile' is not used; you're not properly dealing with the 'FileInputStream' (use try-catch-finally); the loop for reading from the file is ineffective; use exception.printStackTrace() to print the exception

Comment: According to the following website, the byte layout of .au files is: 4 bytes magic word, 4 bytes header size, 4 bytes data size, 4 bytes encoding, 4 bytes sample rate, 4 bytes number of channels, and the rest of it represents the music file. Can you let me know if this is correct, or if you know of a web page that shows the byte layout of a .au file? Thanks. http://docs.python.org/2/library/sunau.html

Comment: Have a look at DataInputStream, may be useful